# アイキャッチ画像が表示されません

Tags: php, wordpress

ワードプレスで１からサイトを制作しています。
アイキャッチ画像を固定ページで設定しようとしていますが、表示がありません。
検索をかけたところ表示オプションにある資格にチェックを入れると表示されるとありますが、見当たりません。

また、functions.phpに問題があるのかもしれないと知り、様々なネットのコードを記入しましたが効果がありません、

functions.php

```
<?PHP
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
?>
```

プラグインを無効化したりしていますが、それでもアイキャッチ画像の項目が出ません。
一体どうすればいいでしょうか?

Answer (score 1):

CSS一番上の記述を修正したら治りました。

```css
/*
Theme Name: test
Version: 1.00
*/
```